# Adding Times New Roman to Ghostscript in Ubuntu

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, truetype

Using Ghostscript 8.71 in Ubuntu, but having trouble reading a PDF file that has the times new roman font on all its pages.

I downloaded the msttcorefonts package and created a Fontmap file for Ghostscript, but this just doesnt seem to work.

My Fontmap file looks like this:

```
/Times (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf);
/Times-Roman (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf);
/Times-Bold (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbd.ttf);
/Times-BoldItalic (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbi.ttf);
/Times-Italic (/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesi.ttf);
```

The Ghostscript command I use:

```
gs -sFONTMAP=/usr/share/ghostscript/8.71/Fontmap bad.pdf -o good.pdf
```

And this is the error I get:

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.71 (2010-02-10)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 3.
Page 1
Error: /undefined in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:5/14(L)--   F2   11.0   FontObject   --dict:8/8(L)--   --dict:8/8(L)--   397   --dict:8/8(L)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   3   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1151/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:288/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:25/40(L)--   --dict:1151/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:10/10(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Could anyone please help me on this? I feel like I've exhausted all possibilities that I can think of.

Here is the PDF file I'm trying to run through Ghostscript: [bad.pdf](http://www.asmeengineering.co.uk/bad.pdf)

If I load all fonts like so:

```
gs -c 'loadallfonts quit'
```

Then the only references to the Times New Roman font is:

```
Loading TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT font from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbi.ttf... 4310316 2923512 4001304 2206507 1 done.
```

Reading the properties of the attached PDF, I can see the font it actually wants is **TimesNewRomainPSMT**. Why is gs not loading all fonts in the msttcorefonts folder?

Comment: Your missing a semicolon off the end of first line.

Comment: And you say the file contains the font Times New Roman, yet you don't seem to have defined a substitute for that, just the Times family. Given that you get an error on 'run' I feel sure Fred F is correct.

Comment: I've made sure there is no missing semicolon but still I get the same error. I've also added a link to the PDF I'm trying to run through Ghostscript. Is anyone able to help further please? Massive thanks. [bad.pdf](http://www.asmeengineering.co.uk/bad.pdf)

Comment: *PSMT is just the font Adobe Acrobat _uses_, it's not the fontname from the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `pdffonts` utility reports about `bad.pdf`:

```
pdffonts bad.pdf 
name                        type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
--------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                 Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      12  0
DejaVuSerifCondensed        Type 1            WinAnsi          yes no  no      13  0
DejaVuSansCondensed         Type 1            WinAnsi          yes no  no      16  0
DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold    Type 1            WinAnsi          yes no  no      19  0
```

This means the following:

1. The font's name which is not embedded is `Times-Roman`, not `TimesNewRomanPSMT` as you think. (I guess you used the Adobe Acrobat/Reader *"file properties"* dialog to look at the font properties? And there you saw this font name tagged as *"Actual Font"* or similar? This means that Acrobat is using this font named `TimesNewRomanPSMT` as a ***substitute***, because it does not have a font named `Times-Roman` itself!)
2. There are 3 fonts from the `DejaVu` family embedded. These are not subsetted, but embedded as full fonts.

So far, so good...

Or?

Now see what happens if I try to let the newest Ghostscript version, compiled from current Git sources, process this `bad.pdf`:

```
    gs -o new.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite bad.pdf

 GPL Ghostscript GIT PRERELEASE 9.16 (2014-09-22)
 Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
 Processing pages 1 through 3.
 Page 1
   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
 Substituting font Helvetica-Narrow for DejaVuSerifCondensed.
 Loading NimbusSanL-ReguCond font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-ReguCond... 4671296 3041958 2433440 1055875 3 done.
 Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu... 4688240 3115971 2494016 1110728 3 done.
 Page 2
   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
 Substituting font Helvetica-Narrow for DejaVuSerifCondensed.
 Page 3
   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
 Substituting font Helvetica-Narrow for DejaVuSerifCondensed.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** ====== mPDF 4.6 ======
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

Your ***embedded*** fonts cannot be processed by Ghostscript.

***There seems to be much more wrong with this particular PDF than what you think.***

Comment: Thank you Kurt for your comprehensive response - very much appreciated. I shall investigate other avenues based on your findings. Thank you.

Comment: Yep! Got called away mid-flow...you know how it is to be a developer ;-)